# Dataframe timestamp interpolation for multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with three columns: `timestamp`, `variable_name` and `value`. There is a total of 10 variables whose names are in the `variable_name` column.

I would like to have a single dataframe, indexed by timestamp, with one column per variable. Ideally, the dataframe should be "full", i.e. each timestamp should have an interpolate value for each variable.

I'm struggling to find a direct way to do that (without looping over the variable list, etc.). The dataframe comes from Spark but is small enough to be converted to Pandas. Any pointers will be most welcome.

Comment: You might be looking for a simple [pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot.html). But please provide code to set up the dataframe and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

> df.loc[:, ['timestamp','variable_name','values']].pivot(index='timestamp',columns='variable_name')

should do the trick